# error while installing dependencies from requirement.txt in virtualenv

Tags: python-3.x, virtualenv, lxml, coala

I created a virtualenv named bug and was trying to install modules from a requirements.txt file using -

pip3 install -r requirements.txt

While installing the modules using above command I am getting the following error. I am using Python3 and trying to install dependencies for coala-quickstart. Following are the message that terminal is giving while tring to install modules from requirements.txt.

```
    Collecting lxml==3.6.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
  Using cached lxml-3.6.0.tar.gz
Collecting coala_bears~=0.12.0.dev20170722110839 (from -r requirements.txt (line 3))
  Using cached coala_bears-0.12.0.dev20171016162004-py34.py35.py36-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): coala_utils~=0.6.6 in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 4))
Collecting gemfileparser~=0.6.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 5))
Collecting pyjsparser~=2.4.5 (from -r requirements.txt (line 6))
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): autopep8~=1.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from coala_bears~=0.12.0.dev20170722110839->-r requirements.txt (line 3))
Collecting yapf~=0.16.0 (from coala_bears~=0.12.0.dev20170722110839->-r requirements.txt (line 3))
  Using cached yapf-0.16.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): nltk~=3.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from coala_bears~=0.12.0.dev20170722110839->-r requirements.txt (line 3))
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): munkres3~=1.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from coala_bears~=0.12.0.dev20170722110839->-r requirements.txt (line 3))
Collecting pyflakes~=1.5.0 (from coala_bears~=0.12.0.dev20170722110839->-r requirements.txt (line 3))
  Using cached pyflakes-1.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): click==6.6 in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from coala_bears~=0.12.0.dev20170722110839->-r requirements.txt (line 3))
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): safety~=0.5.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from coala_bears~=0.12.0.dev20170722110839->-r requirements.txt (line 3))
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): yamllint~=1.6.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from coala_bears~=0.12.0.dev20170722110839->-r requirements.txt (line 3))
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): isort~=4.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from coala_bears~=0.12.0.dev20170722110839->-r requirements.txt (line 3))
Collecting HTTPolice~=0.5.2 (from coala_bears~=0.12.0.dev20170722110839->-r requirements.txt (line 3))
  Using cached HTTPolice-0.5.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting vulture~=0.25.0 (from coala_bears~=0.12.0.dev20170722110839->-r requirements.txt (line 3))
  Using cached vulture-0.25-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting autoflake~=0.7 (from coala_bears~=0.12.0.dev20170722110839->-r requirements.txt (line 3))
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): eradicate~=0.1.6 in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from coala_bears~=0.12.0.dev20170722110839->-r requirements.txt (line 3))
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pylint~=1.6 in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from coala_bears~=0.12.0.dev20170722110839->-r requirements.txt (line 3))
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): cpplint~=1.3 in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from coala_bears~=0.12.0.dev20170722110839->-r requirements.txt (line 3))
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): radon==1.4.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from coala_bears~=0.12.0.dev20170722110839->-r requirements.txt (line 3))
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pycodestyle~=2.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from coala_bears~=0.12.0.dev20170722110839->-r requirements.txt (line 3))
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): cppclean~=0.12.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from coala_bears~=0.12.0.dev20170722110839->-r requirements.txt (line 3))
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): restructuredtext-lint~=1.0.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from coala_bears~=0.12.0.dev20170722110839->-r requirements.txt (line 3))
Collecting coala>=0.12.0.dev20170828055500 (from coala_bears~=0.12.0.dev20170722110839->-r requirements.txt (line 3))
  Using cached coala-0.12.0.dev20171020131504-py34.py35.py36-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): proselint~=0.7.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from coala_bears~=0.12.0.dev20170722110839->-r requirements.txt (line 3))
Collecting docutils-ast-writer~=0.1.2 (from coala_bears~=0.12.0.dev20170722110839->-r requirements.txt (line 3))
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): guess-language-spirit~=0.5.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from coala_bears~=0.12.0.dev20170722110839->-r requirements.txt (line 3))
Collecting pydocstyle~=2.0 (from coala_bears~=0.12.0.dev20170722110839->-r requirements.txt (line 3))
  Using cached pydocstyle-2.1.1-py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): cmakelint~=1.3 in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from coala_bears~=0.12.0.dev20170722110839->-r requirements.txt (line 3))
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): scspell3k~=2.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from coala_bears~=0.12.0.dev20170722110839->-r requirements.txt (line 3))
Collecting aenum~=2.0.8 (from coala_bears~=0.12.0.dev20170722110839->-r requirements.txt (line 3))
  Using cached aenum-2.0.8-py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): dennis~=0.8 in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from coala_bears~=0.12.0.dev20170722110839->-r requirements.txt (line 3))
Collecting apertium-lint~=0.29 (from coala_bears~=0.12.0.dev20170722110839->-r requirements.txt (line 3))
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): bandit~=1.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from coala_bears~=0.12.0.dev20170722110839->-r requirements.txt (line 3))
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): html-linter~=0.3.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from coala_bears~=0.12.0.dev20170722110839->-r requirements.txt (line 3))
Collecting memento-client~=0.6.1 (from coala_bears~=0.12.0.dev20170722110839->-r requirements.txt (line 3))
  Using cached memento_client-0.6.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pyroma~=2.2.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from coala_bears~=0.12.0.dev20170722110839->-r requirements.txt (line 3))
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): mypy-lang~=0.4.6 in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from coala_bears~=0.12.0.dev20170722110839->-r requirements.txt (line 3))
Collecting vim-vint~=0.3.12 (from coala_bears~=0.12.0.dev20170722110839->-r requirements.txt (line 3))
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): nbformat~=4.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from coala_bears~=0.12.0.dev20170722110839->-r requirements.txt (line 3))
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pyprint==0.2.* in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from coala_utils~=0.6.6->-r requirements.txt (line 4))
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pyreadline~=2.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from coala_utils~=0.6.6->-r requirements.txt (line 4))
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): appdirs==1.4.* in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from coala_utils~=0.6.6->-r requirements.txt (line 4))
Collecting nose (from gemfileparser~=0.6.2->-r requirements.txt (line 5))
  Using cached nose-1.3.7-py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): packaging in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from safety~=0.5.1->coala_bears~=0.12.0.dev20170722110839->-r requirements.txt (line 3))
Collecting singledispatch>=3.4.0.3 (from HTTPolice~=0.5.2->coala_bears~=0.12.0.dev20170722110839->-r requirements.txt (line 3))
  Using cached singledispatch-3.4.0.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting defusedxml>=0.5.0 (from HTTPolice~=0.5.2->coala_bears~=0.12.0.dev20170722110839->-r requirements.txt (line 3))
  Using cached defusedxml-0.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting bitstring>=3.1.4 (from HTTPolice~=0.5.2->coala_bears~=0.12.0.dev20170722110839->-r requirements.txt (line 3))
Collecting dominate>=2.2.0 (from HTTPolice~=0.5.2->coala_bears~=0.12.0.dev20170722110839->-r requirements.txt (line 3))
Collecting brotlipy>=0.5.1 (from HTTPolice~=0.5.2->coala_bears~=0.12.0.dev20170722110839->-r requirements.txt (line 3))
  Using cached brotlipy-0.7.0-cp35-cp35m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): astroid>=1.5.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from pylint~=1.6->coala_bears~=0.12.0.dev20170722110839->-r requirements.txt (line 3))
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): mccabe in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from pylint~=1.6->coala_bears~=0.12.0.dev20170722110839->-r requirements.txt (line 3))
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): mando<0.4,>=0.3 in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from radon==1.4.0->coala_bears~=0.12.0.dev20170722110839->-r requirements.txt (line 3))
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): colorama<0.4,>=0.3 in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from radon==1.4.0->coala_bears~=0.12.0.dev20170722110839->-r requirements.txt (line 3))
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): docutils<1.0,>=0.11 in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from restructuredtext-lint~=1.0.0->coala_bears~=0.12.0.dev20170722110839->-r requirements.txt (line 3))
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): setuptools>=17.0 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from coala>=0.12.0.dev20170828055500->coala_bears~=0.12.0.dev20170722110839->-r requirements.txt (line 3))
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): colorlog~=2.7 in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from coala>=0.12.0.dev20170828055500->coala_bears~=0.12.0.dev20170722110839->-r requirements.txt (line 3))
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): unidiff~=0.5.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from coala>=0.12.0.dev20170828055500->coala_bears~=0.12.0.dev20170722110839->-r requirements.txt (line 3))
Collecting testfixtures~=4.14.3 (from coala>=0.12.0.dev20170828055500->coala_bears~=0.12.0.dev20170722110839->-r requirements.txt (line 3))
  Using cached testfixtures-4.14.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): dependency-management~=0.4.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from coala>=0.12.0.dev20170828055500->coala_bears~=0.12.0.dev20170722110839->-r requirements.txt (line 3))
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): libclang-py3~=3.4.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from coala>=0.12.0.dev20170828055500->coala_bears~=0.12.0.dev20170722110839->-r requirements.txt (line 3))
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): Pygments~=2.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from coala>=0.12.0.dev20170828055500->coala_bears~=0.12.0.dev20170722110839->-r requirements.txt (line 3))
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): future in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from proselint~=0.7.0->coala_bears~=0.12.0.dev20170722110839->-r requirements.txt (line 3))
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): snowballstemmer in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from pydocstyle~=2.0->coala_bears~=0.12.0.dev20170722110839->-r requirements.txt (line 3))
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): polib>=1.0.8 in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from dennis~=0.8->coala_bears~=0.12.0.dev20170722110839->-r requirements.txt (line 3))
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): stevedore>=1.17.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from bandit~=1.2->coala_bears~=0.12.0.dev20170722110839->-r requirements.txt (line 3))
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): GitPython>=1.0.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from bandit~=1.2->coala_bears~=0.12.0.dev20170722110839->-r requirements.txt (line 3))
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): docopt>=0.6.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from html-linter~=0.3.0->coala_bears~=0.12.0.dev20170722110839->-r requirements.txt (line 3))
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): template-remover in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from html-linter~=0.3.0->coala_bears~=0.12.0.dev20170722110839->-r requirements.txt (line 3))
Collecting ansicolor~=0.2.4 (from vim-vint~=0.3.12->coala_bears~=0.12.0.dev20170722110839->-r requirements.txt (line 3))
  Using cached ansicolor-0.2.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting typing>=3.6.2 (from vim-vint~=0.3.12->coala_bears~=0.12.0.dev20170722110839->-r requirements.txt (line 3))
  Using cached typing-3.6.2-py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): chardet>=2.3.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from vim-vint~=0.3.12->coala_bears~=0.12.0.dev20170722110839->-r requirements.txt (line 3))
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): jsonschema!=2.5.0,>=2.4 in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from nbformat~=4.1->coala_bears~=0.12.0.dev20170722110839->-r requirements.txt (line 3))
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): ipython-genutils in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from nbformat~=4.1->coala_bears~=0.12.0.dev20170722110839->-r requirements.txt (line 3))
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): traitlets>=4.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from nbformat~=4.1->coala_bears~=0.12.0.dev20170722110839->-r requirements.txt (line 3))
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): jupyter-core in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from nbformat~=4.1->coala_bears~=0.12.0.dev20170722110839->-r requirements.txt (line 3))
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): termcolor~=1.1.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from pyprint==0.2.*->coala_utils~=0.6.6->-r requirements.txt (line 4))
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): idna<2.7,>=2.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from requests->safety~=0.5.1->coala_bears~=0.12.0.dev20170722110839->-r requirements.txt (line 3))
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): urllib3<1.23,>=1.21.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from requests->safety~=0.5.1->coala_bears~=0.12.0.dev20170722110839->-r requirements.txt (line 3))
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): certifi>=2017.4.17 in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from requests->safety~=0.5.1->coala_bears~=0.12.0.dev20170722110839->-r requirements.txt (line 3))
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pyparsing in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from packaging->safety~=0.5.1->coala_bears~=0.12.0.dev20170722110839->-r requirements.txt (line 3))
Collecting cffi>=1.0.0 (from brotlipy>=0.5.1->HTTPolice~=0.5.2->coala_bears~=0.12.0.dev20170722110839->-r requirements.txt (line 3))
  Using cached cffi-1.11.2-cp35-cp35m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): wrapt in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from astroid>=1.5.1->pylint~=1.6->coala_bears~=0.12.0.dev20170722110839->-r requirements.txt (line 3))
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): lazy-object-proxy in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from astroid>=1.5.1->pylint~=1.6->coala_bears~=0.12.0.dev20170722110839->-r requirements.txt (line 3))
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): sarge~=0.1.4 in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from dependency-management~=0.4.0->coala>=0.12.0.dev20170828055500->coala_bears~=0.12.0.dev20170722110839->-r requirements.txt (line 3))
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pbr!=2.1.0,>=2.0.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from stevedore>=1.17.1->bandit~=1.2->coala_bears~=0.12.0.dev20170722110839->-r requirements.txt (line 3))
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): gitdb2>=2.0.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from GitPython>=1.0.1->bandit~=1.2->coala_bears~=0.12.0.dev20170722110839->-r requirements.txt (line 3))
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): decorator in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from traitlets>=4.1->nbformat~=4.1->coala_bears~=0.12.0.dev20170722110839->-r requirements.txt (line 3))
Collecting pycparser (from cffi>=1.0.0->brotlipy>=0.5.1->HTTPolice~=0.5.2->coala_bears~=0.12.0.dev20170722110839->-r requirements.txt (line 3))
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): smmap2>=2.0.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from gitdb2>=2.0.0->GitPython>=1.0.1->bandit~=1.2->coala_bears~=0.12.0.dev20170722110839->-r requirements.txt (line 3))
Building wheels for collected packages: lxml
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for lxml ... error
  Complete output from command /usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-ju97z7yq/lxml/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/tmpjz2njw8dpip-wheel- --python-tag cp35:
  Building lxml version 3.6.0.
  Building without Cython.
  Using build configuration of libxslt 1.1.28
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/lxml
  copying src/lxml/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/lxml
  copying src/lxml/doctestcompare.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/lxml
  copying src/lxml/cssselect.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/lxml
  copying src/lxml/ElementInclude.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/lxml
  copying src/lxml/sax.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/lxml
  copying src/lxml/pyclasslookup.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/lxml
  copying src/lxml/_elementpath.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/lxml
  copying src/lxml/builder.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/lxml
  copying src/lxml/usedoctest.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/lxml
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/lxml/includes
  copying src/lxml/includes/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/lxml/includes
  copying src/lxml/html/defs.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/lxml/html
  copying src/lxml/html/_html5builder.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/lxml/html
  copying src/lxml/html/diff.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/lxml/html
  copying src/lxml/html/clean.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/lxml/html
  copying src/lxml/html/builder.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/lxml/html
  copying src/lxml/html/usedoctest.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/lxml/html
  copying src/lxml/html/_setmixin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/lxml/html
  copying src/lxml/html/soupparser.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/lxml/html
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/lxml/isoschematron
  copying src/lxml/isoschematron/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/lxml/isoschematron
  copying src/lxml/lxml.etree.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/lxml
  copying src/lxml/lxml.etree_api.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/lxml
  copying src/lxml/includes/xmlschema.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/lxml/includes
  copying src/lxml/includes/schematron.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/lxml/includes
  copying src/lxml/includes/xmlerror.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/lxml/includes
  copying src/lxml/includes/xslt.pxd -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/lxml/includes
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/lxml/isoschematron/resources
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/lxml/isoschematron/resources/rng
  copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/rng/iso-schematron.rng -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/lxml/isoschematron/resources/rng
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl
  copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/XSD2Schtrn.xsl -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl
  copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/RNG2Schtrn.xsl -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
  copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_dsdl_include.xsl -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
  copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_svrl_for_xslt1.xsl -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
  copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_abstract_expand.xsl -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
  copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_schematron_message.xsl -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
  copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_schematron_skeleton_for_xslt1.xsl -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
  copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/readme.txt -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
  running build_ext
  building 'lxml.etree' extension
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/src
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/src/lxml
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/usr/include/libxml2 -Isrc/lxml/includes -I/usr/include/python3.5m -c src/lxml/lxml.etree.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/src/lxml/lxml.etree.o -w
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/src/lxml/lxml.etree.o -lxslt -lexslt -lxml2 -lz -lm -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/lxml/etree.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lz
  collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
  error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for lxml
  Running setup.py clean for lxml
Failed to build lxml
Installing collected packages: lxml, yapf, pyflakes, singledispatch, defusedxml, bitstring, dominate, pycparser, cffi, brotlipy, HTTPolice, vulture, autoflake, testfixtures, coala, docutils-ast-writer, pydocstyle, aenum, apertium-lint, memento-client, rstcheck, ansicolor, typing, vim-vint, coala-bears, nose, gemfileparser, pyjsparser
  Found existing installation: lxml 3.5.0
    Not uninstalling lxml at /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages, outside environment /usr
  Running setup.py install for lxml ... error
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-ju97z7yq/lxml/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-pmgvhezd-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    Building lxml version 3.6.0.
    Building without Cython.
    Using build configuration of libxslt 1.1.28
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/lxml
    copying src/lxml/includes/etree_defs.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/lxml/includes
    copying src/lxml/includes/lxml-version.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/lxml/includes
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/lxml/isoschematron/resources
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/lxml/isoschematron/resources/rng
    copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/rng/iso-schematron.rng -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/lxml/isoschematron/resources/rng
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl
    copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/XSD2Schtrn.xsl -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl
    copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/RNG2Schtrn.xsl -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
    copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_dsdl_include.xsl -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
    copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_svrl_for_xslt1.xsl -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
    copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_abstract_expand.xsl -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
    copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_schematron_message.xsl -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
    copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_schematron_skeleton_for_xslt1.xsl -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
    copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/readme.txt -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
    running build_ext
    building 'lxml.etree' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/src
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/src/lxml
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/usr/include/libxml2 -Isrc/lxml/includes -I/usr/include/python3.5m -c src/lxml/lxml.etree.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/src/lxml/lxml.etree.o -w
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/src/lxml/lxml.etree.o -lxslt -lexslt -lxml2 -lz -lm -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/lxml/etree.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
    /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lz
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
  Can't rollback lxml, nothing uninstalled.
Command "/usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-ju97z7yq/lxml/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-pmgvhezd-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-ju97z7yq/lxml/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solved

```
sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev
```

it's ubuntu's tendency to separate dev packages that got someone again. So installing zlib1g won't work by itself. The dev packages must also be installed.

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, it would be preferable to include a description of what this does and how it answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

> cannot find -lz

You need to install `zlib`:

```
apt-get install zlib1g
```

Comment: That's installed

Comment: zlib1g is already the newest version (1:1.2.8.dfsg-2ubuntu4.1).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to create a virtualenv like the following

> Python 3.x

```
virtualenv --system-site-packages -p python3 venv
```

> Python 2.7

```
virtualenv --system-site-packages venv
```

And do not forget to activate your virtualenv by setting

```
souce venv/bin/activate
```

after that you can execute

```
pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: yup I did the same